# How can I create a unique session ID like in JSFiddle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url, url-routing

I would like to create a unique session url for each connection on my website  like on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

I'm using [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/) and [Express](http://expressjs.com/).

The result should be as follow:

for members:

```
https://mywebsite.com/user/uniqueID/
*eg : https://mywebsite.com/user/o2gxgz9r/*
```

for guests:

```
https://mywebsite.com/uniqueID/
eg : *https://mywebsite.com/k36yot0z/*
```

How can I achieve that and is there any specific frameworks for this kind of job?

Comment: Beside using libraries, you can also use [crypto.randomBytes](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many libraries for generating random id, to name a few: nid, uuid, [hyperid](https://github.com/mcollina/hyperid), hashids, shortid, etc..